# IntelliJ IDEA and Play Framework very slow

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am using IDEA 15 for a Play! 2 Application, but I am having problems that the compiler seems to get stuck. Generally when I change a file and save it compiles in a second and I can test. But often it gets 'stuck'.

No warning or message, but refreshing the page just keeps waiting.
And sample is one Scala template which took 43 seconds to compile, and often the only way to get back going is to restart the debug session, but that takes a few minutes as I sometimes have run a 'activator clean' and have to reload all my test data.

Is there a setting somewhere the I might have missed?

Comment: It's hard to say without any code. Was it always like this? Maybe you can share your build file.

Comment: I noticed the exact same thing when moving from IJ 14 to 15 when working in Scala. Play projects primarily using Java don't seem to be as affected.

Comment: Confirm, it happens even on basic projects (just some simple controller and simple view), with no log or something - compiler just freezes for 30-40 seconds.

Comment: I don't know exactly if it was always like this, but it was for me on IDEA 14, as I moved to 15 yesterday to check if that would solve it. This is my first major project on Play! 2(.4) as I have been using Play! 1.2.5 until now.

Comment: I think it might have improved since I turned on the Play 2 compiler in the settings.